# Doing the same thing over and over and getting a different result? Strtok in c. - College student question

Tags: c

So, I'm trying to get input and parse it using delimiters. The input is in the format of L(#,#,#)L where L is a letter and the delimiters are "(),". It works fine the first time I go through this code, but when it gets back to the same area on the second time through strtok cuts off the last token and  instead of catching the 'L' it just sees "\n" instead of "L\n" (it sees "L\n" the first time through) and thus makes the letter 'X' instead of 'L'. This only happens when I use the same letter twice, but if I use different letters (for the last letter) it works. Before you ask, I'm in college and I already had this working using an array to store the different tokens and would personally do it different if able but she has very strict requirements which if you don't follow then you get no credit. I've gone through gdb but as far as I can tell it has something to do with strtok that I haven't been able to find online and isn't obvious through the debugger. And even if I print *tkn-1 at the end then the 'L' is still there. If anybody can help me I would greatly appreciate it!

```
    fgets(usrInpt, MX_INPT - 1, stdin);
    tkn = strtok(usrInpt, dlmtrs);
    cmmndLttr = *tkn;
    if (cmmndLttr!='q' && cmmndLttr!='Q')
    {
        tkn = strtok(NULL, dlmtrs);
        rwPstn = atoi(tkn);
        tkn = strtok(NULL, dlmtrs);
        clPstn = atoi(tkn);
        tkn = strtok(NULL, dlmtrs);
        lnLngth = atoi(tkn);
        tkn = strtok(NULL, dlmtrs);
        if (tkn != NULL)
            lnLttr = *tkn>31?*tkn:'X';
        else
            lnLttr='X';
```

PS: I removed vowels from the variable names since she uses a "plagiarism detector" for code and I want to lessen the chances that I have to deal with that (by it matching my own code).

Comment: Could you please provide example input, expected output and actual output in a compact form? Your longish descriptions aren't really that clear, I'm afraid. For example, what do you mean with "first time through" and "second time through"? Do you tokenize the ssme string twice? (`strtok` modifies the string, so that won't work.)

Comment: First example input : "L(0,0,10)L"
First example output for lnLttr: 'L
Second example input: "L(0,4,10)L"
Second example output for lnLttr: X

This is in a while loop that continues accepting input/runs as long as cmmdLttr (the first letter) isn't 'q' or 'Q'.

I want it to recognize lnLttr is still 'L' for the second input L(

Comment: It won't let me re-edit the first comment since I keep pressing "Enter" submitting it when trying to enter a new line.

First example input : "L(0,0,10)L"
First example output for lnLttr: 'L'
Second example input: "L(0,4,10)L"
Second example output for lnLttr: 'X'

This is in a while loop that continues accepting input/runs as long as cmmdLttr (the first letter) isn't 'q' or 'Q'.

I want it to recognize lnLttr is still 'L' for the second input "L(0,4,10)L" but instead strtok goes to the '\n' on the second input instead of finding the L like it does the first time.

Comment: Please extend the shown source with the `while`-loop, at best provide a [example]. At a first glance I don't see any serious problem in the code as is.

Answer (score 0):

Running this:

```
const char* dlmtrs = "(),";
char str[3][128] = {"L(42,13,12)L\n", "L(0,0,12)L\n", "L(42,0,0)L\n" }; 


for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++ i )
{
    char* token = strtok(str[i], dlmtrs); 

    while (token != NULL) 
    { 
        printf("%s\n", token); 
        token = strtok(NULL, dlmtrs); 
    }
}
```

Still gives the correct output for each input string, see [here](https://onlinegdb.com/SkxLZIpFH)

**EDIT: I changed the snippet to be called in a loop with different values.**

Comment: Yeah, it works witht the first input. But for some reason when I input a second string such as "L(43,2,1)L" it doesn't catch the last 'L' again and instead computes it as 'X' (unlike the first input).

PS: This is in a while loop that continues recieving input until cmndLttr is either 'q' or 'Q'.